# Error importing classes for RDF crawler

Tags: java, rdf, jena

I'm using a rdf crawler, in that I had a class named as:

```java
import edu.unika.aifb.rdf.crawler.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager;
```

These are class file termed as error, and I try with jena packages but I had attached, it does not make any changes.

### Update:

**Full *SampleCrawl.java* class content:**

```java
import java.util.*;
import edu.unika.aifb.rdf.crawler.*;

/**
 * Call this class with 3 arguments - URL to crawl to,
 * depth and time in seconds
 */

public class SampleCrawl {

    /**
     * @param uRI
     * @param depth
     * @param time
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public SampleCrawl(Vector uRI, Vector hf, int depth, int time){

        // Initialize Crawling parameters
        CrawlConsole c = new CrawlConsole(uRI,hf,depth,time);

        // get an ontology file from its local location
        // (OPTIONAL)
        c.setLocalNamespace("http://www.daml.org/2000/10/daml-ont","c:\\temp\\rdf\\schemas\\daml-ont.rdf");

        // set all the paths to get all the results
        c.setLogPath("c:\\temp\\crawllog.xml");
        c.setCachePath("c:\\temp\\crawlcache.txt");
        c.setModelPath("c:\\temp\\crawlmodel.rdf");

        try{
            // crawl and get RDF model
            c.start();

            // This writes all three result files out
            c.writeResults();
        }catch(Exception e){
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        if (args.length != 3) {
            System.err.println("Usage: java  -cp  [JARs]  SampleCrawl  [URL]  [depth:int]  [time:int]");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        Vector uris = new Vector();
        uris.add(args[0]);

        // no host filtering - crawl to all hosts
        Vector hostfilter = null;

        /* You may want to do something else to enable host filtering:
         * Vector hostfilter = new Vector();
         * hostfilter.add("http://www.w3.org");
         */

        int depth = 2;
        int time = 60;
        try {
            depth = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            time = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Illegal argument types:");
            System.err.println("Argument list: URI:String  depth:int  time(s):int");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        new SampleCrawl(uris,hostfilter,depth,time);
    }
}
```

**Question:**
How to add `import edu.unika.aifb.rdf.crawler.;` error occurs here

Comment: Could you provide a fuller code snippet and the error raised?

Comment: here i hve upload the program

Comment: @nihcap: Stop reverting changes that correct punctuation, and remove useless salutations & platitudes.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Sorry, I was moving to question the author's own answer and comment. I was unaware of changes you were making, it was unintentional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I googled the package that you're trying to import, and it appears that you're using Kaon. Assuming that's so, you have made an error in your import declaration. You have:

```
import edu.unika.aifb.rdf.crawler.*;
```

whereas the download available on SourceForge would require:

```
import edu.unika.aifb.rdf.rdfcrawler.*;
```

As an aside, it would be helpful if you would include information, such as *"I'm trying to use Kaon's rdfcrawler from ..."* in your question. Otherwise, we have to try to guess important details in your setup.

Comment: Ok..i got the error fixed up ...but i have another error says